# Йогурт — йогУрт

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

Эта тема уже не раз понималась, но мне интересно узнать участь именно этого слова. Якобы по новым правилам надо говорить "йогУрт". Объясните мне, на каком, вообще, основании? Я понимаю, если бы так кто-то говорил, но я НИ РАЗУ не слышала такого ни от кого! Кому и зачем вообще взбрело в голову так коверкать ударение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно, странная интерпретация обычного для нас слова "йОгурт". "Грамота.ру" дала объяснение , откуда взялось ударение на У. См. http://www.gramota.ru/lenta/news/8_2489 
Тем не менее, Орфоэпический словарь русского языка И.Л. Резниченко. Москва, 2003 допускает такой вариант ударения.
Вот это более чем странно. Ведь так никто не говорит. Йогурты появились в России всего лет двадцать назад, почти одновременно с рекламой. Ни в одной рекламе ни о каких йогУртах никто не слыхивал.
А дело в том, что йогурт - турецкое слово. В XIX в. в турецком языке утвердились два варианта ударения в этом слове, и со временем ударение "переехало" с первого слога на второй. Сегодня турки говорят йогурт, а йогурт считают устаревшей формой. Причём произносят они ёурт, хотя и пишут yoğurt: буква ğ между двумя широкими гласными не произносится.
Но в массовый русский язык это слово попало в 1990-х, и не из турецкого языка, а из английского. А англичане заимствовали его у турок ещё в XVIII веке, со старым ударением, на первом слоге.

Comment: "Сегодня турки говорят йогурт, а йогурт считают устаревшей формой" — по контексту, конечно, понятно, но стоило бы выделить ударные буквы.

Comment: А, если от турков, тогда я могу понять. Во всех тюркских языках ударение ставится на последний слог

Comment: >Во всех тюркских языках ударение ставится на последний слог  
  
Не совсем так. Есть исключения. Конкретно про турецкий: таких слов мало, но в принципе они есть. В наречиях, например, ударение часто падает на второй слог от конца, в существительных, если ударение падает не на последний слог, то оно обычно отмечается на письме специальным значком.

А вообще - см. здесь. http://perevod99.blogspot.de/2011/03/blog-post_776.html

Comment: Я живу в Крыму, много лет работала в крымскотатарской прессе. И ни разу слышала ни одного тюркского слова с ударением НЕ на последний слог.  
Так что мне ссылки на источники заменяет живая речь, которую я слышу почти каждый день)))))

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя взять и внезапно изменить нормы. Я тоже никогда не слышал, чтобы кто-нибудь говорил *"йогУрт"*, но в таких словарях, как, например, *Русский орфографический словарь. / Российская академия наук. Ин-т рус. яз. им. В. В. Виноградова. — М.: "Азбуковник". В. В. Лопатин (ответственный редактор), Б. З. Букчина, Н. А. Еськова и др.. **1999**. и* Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. **2000**. *указаны оба варианта ударения (обратите внимание, что прошло уже 13-14 лет со времени выпуска этих словарей). А например, в *Толковый словарь Ожегова. С.И. Ожегов, Н.Ю. Шведова. **1949-1992**.* и *Большой толковый словарь русского языка. - 1-е изд-е: СПб.: Норинт. С. А. Кузнецов. **1998**.* указан только один вариант ударения — на первый слог.



Составители словарей не берут нормы с потолка, они фиксируют то, что происходит в языке. Следовательно, кто-то всё-таки говорит* "йогУрт"*, поэтому и сделали этот вариант произношения допустимым, но это не значит, что единственно верным. Нет, можете произносить это слово  так, как вам удобно.

Comment: Ну, кто-то говорит и "ложут", но ведь это слово не сделали равнозначным слову "кладут"))))))

Comment: Возможно, когда-нибудь сделают. Очень даже возможно.

Comment: >Возможно, когда-нибудь сделают. Очень даже возможно.  
  
Невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

> Якобы, по новым правилам надо говорить "йогУрт".

Источник этого утверждения не назовёте?  Про *новые* правила?
По "новым" - это как раз йОгурт.

Самое древнее вхождение - Аванесов, 1987: йогУрт.
http://dazor.narod.ru/russkie/slovari/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0199.htm

Ранее йогУрт было единственно нормативным, я до сих пор не могу заставить себя говорить иное. Кстати, не все словари этого требуют. Лопатин даёт два варианта. Но он не авторитет тут, увы...

> Большой толковый словарь русского языка. - 1-е изд-е: СПб.: Норинт. С. А. Кузнецов. 1998. указан только один вариант ударения — на первый слог.

Боже, опять Кузнецов... Уже просто выть хочется от этого областного авторитета... В области орфоэпии. Но тут приходиться признать, что он не одинок. У Зарвы - тоже йОгурт.

> Сегодня турки говорят йогурт, а йогурт считают устаревшей формой. Причём произносят они ёурт, хотя и пишут yoğurt:

Гугл врет?
http://translate.google.ru/?hl=ru&tab=wT#ru/tr/%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D1%82
Можно послушать, можно посмотреть, что нет ударения над гласной (оно обязательно, если ударение падает не на последний слог).
Правда русский вариант произношения гугл даёт вообще смешно... Почти что Ягурт. Но такой вариант в принципе возможен, если следовать правилу чтения безударного О

Comment: Пишем  йогурт,  Говорим, фактически,  ёгурт.  Ё всегда  под  ударением,  если  говорим  на  русском  языке.  И  зачем  нам  турецкие  нормы  произношения ?

Comment: Это кому вопрос? 
Впрочем, насколько понимаю, вопрос в том, как пришло слово в русский язык, и нормы произношения языка-источника тут не последнее дело.  
Впрочем про ударное Ё - это весьма ценное соображение. В том плане, что объясняет смещение ударения на первый слог. 
При ударном втором приходится произносить с некоторым напряжением, отдельно Й, потом О. Но это в принципе противоречит правилам фонетики. 
В частности - безударных. Поэтому вариант "ягУрт" (А < О безуданое) не выглядит совсем уж диким.
Плюсик - за идею.

Answer (score -1):

Зачем нам нужны варианты ударения? Стал ли русский язык лучше, когда к общеизвестному йОгурту добавился йогУрт?  Варианты ударений засоряют наш язык, и задача науки - по возможности сокращать количество вариантов, а не размножать их. И очень жаль, что пользователи языка покорно принимают такие новшества, считая их откровениями свыше.
Прочитайте статью "7 отвергнутых правил грамматике" в Вечерней Москве (3-10 октября). Если не будем возражать против реформ, то скоро будем писать "жжот, отреж" и благодарить наших небожителей за упрощенную орфографию.
Подробности на эту тему в статье "Почему мы не любим, когда нас кодифицируют", см. ресурс http://russianorfo.blogspot.ru/ (искать в Гугл).
   Слово йОгурт  – тюркского происхождения (в современном турецком языке ударение в нем падает на второй слог – йогУрт, вариант йОгурт считается устаревшим). В русский язык слово входило дважды. Первый его вариант,   заимствованный через французский (или болгарский) язык в форме йогУрт,   относится к 20-30-ым годам 20 века – тогда обозначаемый  им продукт  был экзотикой.  В 80-ые годы 20 века слово  йОгурт  входит в наш язык в английском варианте  (с ударением на первом слоге) – при этом оно обозначает вполне реальный предмет и именно в этой форме получает широкое распространение. И теперь вопрос: зачем надо было возрождать его первую, уже основательно забытую форму? Какой смысл был заложен в искусственном создании вариантного произношения?

Comment: Реформы  всегда ( или  часто )  вызывают  неудовольствие.  Потом  к  ним  привыкают.  Потом  помнящие  прежние  нормы  вымирают.  Потом  начинаются  новые  реформы.  И  как  тут  быть ?